# Prevent User to access the file in the resource folder .. hosted on Apache Tomcat

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, tomcat, web

Hello My website address is

### www.abcdef.com/context/index.html

however user is also able to access

### www.abcdef/context/resources/somPngFile.png

which i don't want

(here resources is a folder in which i have kept the image files)

Also I do all the validation and session checking in index.html.If user directly accesses the png file from url he is able to get it. Any slution as how to avoid this are appreciated.
I am using apache tomcat as server and coding in jquery.

Comment: in the index.html or any public pages are you accessing the images from the resources folder? if yes then putting the contents behind a security wall will not work as the public page needs access to those image files as well. look into spring security which will help you in doing what you need but remember if you secure a folder then the contents of that folder cannot be accessed through public pages as well. hope this helps

Comment: When any page will be loaded through index.html , it will check for the session and if legitimate then give access.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like by putting the below code in the web.xml .. thanks for comments though ..

```
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>HTTP-Protected-Resource-1</web-resource-name>
          <description>Description here</description>
          <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>NOSOUPFORYOU</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```